# How to make eyes look at somewhere specific?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have this image. I want to make the character on the right look at the character on the left. She's looking in the right direction, but it doesn't look realistic enough. She's not looking at her eyes. Can I fix this with Photoshop? If yes, how? Can you point me to some resources?

[image]

Comment: If you do not have advanced skills in digital painting, you can not.

Comment: Have you tried the Neural Filters in Photoshop?

Comment: Instead of using AI to generate a slur of pixels you could commission an illustration from an artist who actually knows what they are doing and get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not easy with such a low resolution image, you could just paint a few lighter pixels under her irises. It only has to be very subtle to give the illusion that she has lifted her eyes a little.

An animated example showing the before and after

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not at all easy. Low resolution, so long distance that it's difficult to see both faces at the same time and nothing on the face of the rightmost character hints there's some brain activity. She looks like there's no reason to do anything. The distance and the poker face are fixed in the next image.

[image]

Now she looks more like something is happening under her scalp. The obvious reason is the leftmost character, because there exists nothing else and the eyes also happen to point to the right direction.

Hopefully you see this before it's voted out of the scene. But it's never only the eyes, the whole face matters.